# Processing.js P3D image sizes defaulting to last in stack

Tags: javascript, image, oop, processing.js, image-size

I am working on a processing sketch that I have recently debugged to run on the web with processing.js. It uses P3D rendering to render a 3D globe and then plots points to that globe. Everything is showing on the canvas however after the initial setup the screen glitches and ALL of the images default their width value to the last image in the stack (the globe image). If the images are initiated in the setup they display correctly however when in the draw loop they go crazy. If i instantiate noLoop(); they display correctly however this stops the globe from also being able to be animated. I have been trying to debug this all day but cant figure out what is going on: please help. You can see the ["working" file  here](http://dofficial.com/prototypes/Earthquakes/) to see what I mean.

```
/* @pjs preload="Title.png,img/dial.png,img/dialface.jpg,img/world32k.jpg"; */

PImage texmap;
PImage img;
PImage img2; 
PImage imgTitle;

int sDetail = 35;  // Sphere detail setting

float globeRadius = 250;
float pushBack = 0;

float[] cx, cz, sphereX, sphereY, sphereZ;


void setup() {

  size(1350, 800, P3D);  
  imageMode(CENTER);
  imgTitle = loadImage("Title.png");
  img = loadImage("img/dialface.jpg");
  img2 = loadImage("img/dial.png");
  texmap = loadImage("img/world32k.jpg");   


}

void draw() {    
  background(0); 
  noStroke();
  drawDial();
 renderGlobe();   

}
void renderGlobe() {
  pushMatrix();
  translate(429, 320, pushBack);
  textureMode(IMAGE);  
  texturedSphere(globeRadius, texmap);
  popMatrix();

}
        void drawDial(){    
      pushMatrix();
      image(img, 885, 487, 415, 313);
      image(imgTitle, 700, 50, 600, 200);
      translate(1064.5, 487, 1);
      image(img2,0, 0, 159, 200);
      noStroke();
      popMatrix();

    }




// Draw texture sphere
void texturedSphere(float r, PImage t) {
  int v1,v11,v2; 
  beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
  texture(t);
  float iu=(float)(t.width-1)/(sDetail);
  float iv=(float)(t.height-1)/(sDetail);
  float u=0,v=iv;
  for (int i = 0; i < sDetail; i++) {
    vertex(0, -r, 0,u,0);
    vertex(sphereX[i]*r, sphereY[i]*r, sphereZ[i]*r, u, v);
    u+=iu;
  }
  vertex(0, -r, 0,u,0);
  vertex(sphereX[0]*r, sphereY[0]*r, sphereZ[0]*r, u, v);
  endShape();   

  // Middle rings
  int voff = 0;
  for(int i = 2; i < sDetail; i++) {
    v1=v11=voff;
    voff += sDetail;
    v2=voff;
    u=0;
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    texture(t);
    for (int j = 0; j < sDetail; j++) {
      vertex(sphereX[v1]*r, sphereY[v1]*r, sphereZ[v1++]*r, u, v);
      vertex(sphereX[v2]*r, sphereY[v2]*r, sphereZ[v2++]*r, u, v+iv);
      u+=iu;
    }

    // Close each ring
    v1=v11;
    v2=voff;
    vertex(sphereX[v1]*r, sphereY[v1]*r, sphereZ[v1]*r, u, v);
    vertex(sphereX[v2]*r, sphereY[v2]*r, sphereZ[v2]*r, u, v+iv);
    endShape();
    v+=iv;
  }
  u=0;

  // Add the northern cap
  beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
  texture(t);
  for (int i = 0; i < sDetail; i++) {
    v2 = voff + i;
    vertex(sphereX[v2]*r, sphereY[v2]*r, sphereZ[v2]*r, u, v);
    vertex(0, r, 0,u,v+iv);    
    u+=iu;
  }
  vertex(sphereX[voff]*r, sphereY[voff]*r, sphereZ[voff]*r, u, v);
  endShape();

}
```

Comment: very difficult to debug with the mass of code you have. Narrow down where you think the problem is.

Comment: @Cfreak Ok I have simplified the code to show what is the problem. The sphere renders fine so I removed that part but once I map the image to the sphere it resizes img, imgTitle, img2. You can briefly see the sizes they are supposed to be when the page loads but it seems when the draw() loops all of the images default to the width of the globe. I had this same problem when trying to resize the images but when I resaved the .pngs at the dimensions I wanted everything fit; as soon as I added to texture map to the sphere it broke again and since it is not a square image I cannot specify a width.

Comment: If you click on the link above (in firefox or chrome) and refresh the page a few times youll see the two images on the right load and resize

Comment: Can you upload the file in its current form...that is, the .pde with all the data zipped or something so I can run it on my computer. I think it may have to do with pushMatrix() and popMatrix() but I want to make sure.

Comment: Ok [here is the current version of the sketch](http://www.dofficial.com/prototypes/sphere_debug.zip)

Comment: if you can reduce this to an example that does nothing other that set up the code to demonstrate the problem, this is worth filing over at the Pjs issue tracker on github